# Laplace Operator Times Function

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm just going through some proofs of a PDE book and have a question about one of them.
It is stated that:

$$
\int_U w \Delta w \text{ d}x = -2 \int_U |Dw|^2 \text{ d}x
$$

Where $w$ is a solution of the following problem:

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rll}
-\Delta w&=0&\text{ in }U_T,\\
w&=0&\text{ in }\Gamma_T, .
\end{array}\right.
$$

Can someone explain why this is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints**

1. Notice the general identity

$$\psi \nabla ^2 \phi=\nabla \cdot (\psi \nabla \phi)-\nabla \psi \cdot \nabla \phi \tag{1}$$

2. Integrate over the domain
3. Use the divergence theorem
4. Put $\psi=\phi$

Comment: All clear, thank you very much.